# What does it mean by accessing a relational table?

Tags: sql, database, indexing, relational-database

So i have a relational table:

> BOOK(bNum, bName, bPubDate, bSubject, bCost)

and an index

> ID(bPubDate, bSubject, bCost)

I am tasked to execute a SQL statement that will use the index in the following way:

> Execution of SELECT statement must traverse the index
>   vertically and it must not access a relational table BOOK.

What is confusing me is the statement "**must not access a relational table BOOK**".

Does that mean that if i were to select something that is not in the index, it will be accessing the relational table?

e.g.

```
SELECT bName FROM BOOK;
```

Does it also mean that if i were to select something that is part of the index, it will not be accessing the relational table?

e.g.

```
SELECT bPubDate, bSubject, bCost FROM BOOK;
```

Hope someone can clarify this for me. Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, the question is asking for a covering index, so the query does not access the data pages.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oracle database.

Comment: Reading around.. I've found that Index organised tables allow the access of data without accessing the table.

https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Index-organized_table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that mean that if i were to select something that is not in the index, it will be accessing the relational table?

Yes, that is correct.

> Does it also mean that if i were to select something that is part of the index, it will not be accessing the relational table?
>
> e.g.
>
> SELECT bPubDate, bSubject, bCost FROM BOOK;

Yes, the example query you gave should satisfy the question.  If you want to make sure that you also "traverse the index vertically", you might want to `ORDER BY` the columns in the index as well:

`SELECT bPubDate, bSubject, bCost FROM BOOK ORDER BY bPubDate, bSubject, bCost`

Although I suspect the `ORDER BY` is unnecessary and the results will end up in that order anyways.